# Lower the speed of a certain connected pc to the wifi?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet

Our internet speed isnt that fast and this idiot keeps on connecting on our wifi and is it possible to lower his speed? I dont wanna completely block him.

Comment: Can you tell us the make and model of the wireless access point (AP) and/or router that you are using? We need to know this so we can find out if they can do what you are asking about.

Comment: I hope you have encryption set up? If you have an open AP, you SERIOUSLY want to reconsider - anyone can sniff your traffic.

Comment: +1 on that comment for encryption... leaving wifi open is bad for dozens of reasons... if you want to block him, switch to wpa2.

Comment: Why not completely block him? If you are insistent on that approach, you can look at QoS by device, some routers can do that. You can basically prioritize his traffic to be the lowest (here is an example of doing it on a linksys router: http://kb.linksys.com/Linksys/ukp.aspx?pid=80&vw=1&articleid=1701)

Comment: I dont wanna block him. I just wanna lower his speed so i dont have a slow connection myself.

Comment: @K.A TP-LINK
150M Wireless Lite N Router
Model No. TL-WR740N / TL-WR740ND

Comment: http://www.tp-link.com/Resources/document/TL-WR740N_741ND_User_Guide.pdf - section 4.13.2 (page 77) - you can limit bandwidth per IP (you would first want to utilize section 4.7.3 on page 48 to lock his MAC to an IP so you can ensure the rule always applies to him).

Comment: @MaQleod Thanks! Thats exactly what i need. But, im having trouble assigning an ip myself for his mac address. Cause in my wired connection, i think it generates random ip addreses every reboot (i think thats the normal thing). So.. how is that gonna work?

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable QoS on the OUTGOING leg of the connection, which practically means doing bandwidth limiting on the router as its the only device which can do outgoing limiting both to and from a device.

Whether your device is able to limit bandwidth per device is really up to the individual router, but you will find most off-the-shelf routers have no or very limited ability to do this - but flashing the router with DD-WRT or similar will provide this kind of functionality if enabled.

Another possibility might be to get a second WIFI router, enable encryption for WIFI on your main WIFI device and daisy chain the second WIFI via Ethernet - with a different AP name, making sure the second AP has QoS functionality - If you have a spare AP lying arround which doesn't have QoS it might be worth trying anyway  - just configure it to 802.11b which will limit his speed and range (this is very crude and might not be a tight enough limit - but it should also deprioritize him slightly as he will have higher latency)

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to lower his speed?

Yes, but *probably* not with the equipment you've got.

The answer depends on your router hardware, your router firmware, your technical ability, and your desire to learn about and mess around with configurations or buy, install, and learn to administer a hardware or software firewall.

And if the "idiot" is tech savvy himself, he'd be able to bypass most solutions by spoofing his MAC address or even just switching to another adapter. So you could possibly spend hours and money on the speed-reduction project, only to have him evade you in a few minutes anyway.

The best approach here is probably social rather than technical engineering: just talk to the guy. Maybe he can limit his activity to the hours when others are out or asleep, or some other compromise can be struck so that all users are happy about sharing the connection.

Answer (score -1):

As suggested in the comments, the best way to block that person is to setup Encryption.

Some others would suggest setting access restriction using MAC-Address of that particular PC, but that access restriction can be bypassed very easy.

Comment: I said i dont wanna block him. Just lower his speed so i dont have a slow connection

Comment: i know that, and even if that was possible with you hardware, having a wifi access open to everyone is posing a threat - to your network security and to yours possible as well.

Comment: In addition, with an open wifi access, others, aside from the "idiot" when connected to your network will consume bandwidth, further degrading your connection.

Comment: Likewise, as queried above, knowing your AP/router is important so that so people who would want to assist would know the capabilities of your AP/router.